# Who's responsible for creating the MainViewController instance in the iPhone NavBar example

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, model-view-controller, interface-builder

I'm exploring [the NavBar example](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/NavBar/index.html) from the iPhone dev center.

More specifically, I'm trying to understand where the MainViewController object is instantiated and I simply can't find where this is happening.

The only references to the MainViewController class is in AppDelegate, where there is a forward declaration and #import.  However, removing these sentences doesn't affect the program whatsoever.

The object is probably created in the nib file, but again, I can't find it.

I really like the Xcode development environment.  What I don't like, however, is that there are some many different places where objects can be created/connected that it makes it really hard to understand somebody else's code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you look in the MainWIndow.xib file and click the disclosure triangle next to "Navigation Controller", you'll see an instance of MainViewController. This was created by dragging a "View Controller" object from the Library  and then changing its Class.